# Нет доступа к приложению на azure vm

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

Поднял вм на azure. На вм поднимаю спринг бутовое приложение на 8081 порту. В настройках ажура везде выставил порты, но доступа к приложению через браузер нет. На самой вм через локалхост - все ок.

Никто не сталкивался с таким?

Answer (score 1):

Отключение брандмауэра на вм решило проблему :)

Answer (score 1):

Да, все правильно. Нужно не только открыть порты для виртуальной машины windows cо стороны Ажура, но также настроить правила на файрвол самой операционный системы.

Здесь описание как открыть порты со стороны Ажур Платформы:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

А здесь пример как можно открыть порты внутри самой операционной системы.
https://pcfaq.info/internet-i-seti/kak_otkryt_porty_v_windows.html

Cостояние порта должно быть Listening.